# Why isn't my vue infinite scroll not returning profiles?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I've got an firestore database and I'm trying to use an infinite scroll on the profile page to load all the profiles but it isn't even getting the data from the database because I should be seeing the documents data appear in the console log.
this is the javascript page which gets the documents and limits them to 8.

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";



const fetchPosts = async (lastPost) => {
    let query = projectFirestore.collection('Premium').orderBy('createdAt').limit(8)
    
    if (lastPost) {
      query = query.startAfter(lastPost.createdAt)
    }
  
    const snapshot = await query.get()
  
    const posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())
      return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }
    })
  
    return posts
  }
  export default fetchPosts
```

this is the vue side

```
<script>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import fetchPosts  from '../../Composables/limitedProfiles'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      posts: [],
      lastPost: null,
      fetching: false
    })

    const container = ref(null)

    const handleScroll = async () => {
      if (container.value.scrollTop + container.value.clientHeight >= container.value.scrollHeight && !state.fetching) {
        state.fetching = true

        const posts = await fetchPosts(state.lastPost)
        state.posts = [...state.posts, ...posts]

        if (posts.length) {
          state.lastPost = posts[posts.length - 1]
        }

        state.fetching = false
      }
    }

    return {
      container,
      handleScroll,
      ...state
    }
  }
}

</script>
<template>
    <br><br>
    <p class="text-5xl text-red-700 font-serif">Infinite scroll</p><br><br><br>
    <div ref="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      
      <div class= "hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-900 active:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 font-bold rounded-xl">
  <br>
     <p>{{ post.Name }}</p>
     <img :src= "post.Pic1" class="object-contain ml-6 w-60 h-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300">
     <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
     <p>Location:</p>
     <p>{{ post.Location }}</p>
     <p>detail1:</p>
     <p>{{ post.detail1 }} /hr</p>
     <p>detail2:</p>
     <p>{{ post.detail2 }}</p>
     <p>detail3:</p>
     <p>{{ post.detail3 }}</p>
    </div>
  </div><br>
</div>
    <div v-if="fetching">Loading...
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

If anyone could take a look and let me know what I might be doing wrong I'd appreciate it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't flat `reactive` object! if you flat it with `spread dot` there is no way to react the values

```js
<script>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import fetchPosts  from '../../Composables/limitedProfiles'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      posts: [],
      lastPost: null,
      fetching: false
    })

    const container = ref(null)

    const handleScroll = async () => {
      if (container.value.scrollTop + container.value.clientHeight >= container.value.scrollHeight && !state.fetching) {
        state.fetching = true

        const posts = await fetchPosts(state.lastPost)
        state.posts = [...state.posts, ...posts]

        if (posts.length) {
          state.lastPost = posts[posts.length - 1]
        }

        state.fetching = false
      }
    }

    return {
      container,
      handleScroll,
      state
    }
  }
}

</script>

<template>
    <br><br>
    <p class="text-5xl text-red-700 font-serif">Infinite scroll</p><br><br><br>
    <div ref="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
    <div v-for="post in state.posts" :key="post.id">
      
      <div class= "hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-900 active:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 font-bold rounded-xl">
  <br>
     <p>{{ post.Name }}</p>
     <img :src= "post.Pic1" class="object-contain ml-6 w-60 h-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300">
     <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
     <p>Location:</p>
     <p>{{ post.Location }}</p>
     <p>detail1:</p>
     <p>{{ post.detail1 }} /hr</p>
     <p>detail2:</p>
     <p>{{ post.detail2 }}</p>
     <p>detail3:</p>
     <p>{{ post.detail3 }}</p>
    </div>
  </div><br>
</div>
    <div v-if="state.fetching">Loading...
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

also `handleScroll` is not `immediate` so `container` won't overflow and `scroll` event can't happen it has many problems and you better review the logic of your code